# pyshp Create Multipatch cube

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp, multipatch

I am trying to create a Multipatch Shapefile in the shape of a cube. I am using pyshp library and could create one face as a 3D Polygon as described in the wiki of pyshp ([Creating 3D Polygons](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp/1.2.0#adding-geometry)). However, I am not able to create a multipatch geometry, probably because I do not use the right order of coordinates or something like that. Here is my Code using the coordinate order described by esri ([Link](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/multipatch-geometry-type.pdf), doc Page 35):

```
w = shapefile.Writer(shapeType=shapefile.MULTIPATCH)
w.poly(parts=[[[0,0,0] , [0,0,1] , [0,1,1] , [0,0,0]] , [[0,0,0] , [1,0,0] , [1,1,0] , [0,0,0]],
        [[0,1,0] , [0,1,1] , [0,0,0] , [0,1,0]] , [[0,0,0] , [0,1,1] , [0,0,1] ,[0,0,0]],
        [[1,1,0] , [0,1,1] , [0,1,0] ,[1,1,0]], [[1,1,0] , [1,1,1] , [0,1,1]] ,
        [[1,0,0] , [1,1,1] , [1,1,0] ,[1,0,0]], [[1,0,0] , [1,0,1] , [1,1,1]] ,
        [[0,0,0] , [0,0,1] , [1,0,0] ,[0,0,0]], [[1,0,0] , [0,0,1] , [1,0,1]] ,
        [[0,0,1] , [0,1,1] , [1,1,1] ,[0,0,1]], [[0,0,1] , [1,1,1] , [1,0,1]]], shapeType=31)
w.field("NAME")
w.record("PolyZTest")
w.save("shapefiles/test/MyPolyS")
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the usage of `poly()` wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You're close - just a few minor issues.

Multipatch shapefiles need a specialized type for each part which can be:

```
VALUE  PART TYPE
0      Triangle Strip
1      Triangle Fan
2      Outer Ring
3      Inner Ring
4      First Ring
5      Ring
```

In pyshp, this is defined in your parts array using the array "partTypes"

All polygons must move in clockwise order which I didn't double-check in your example.  I created my own coordinates to be sure and used the rest of your code verbatim to create a working cube:

```
import shapefile

w = shapefile.Writer(shapeType=shapefile.MULTIPATCH)
w.poly(parts=[
[[0,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,1], [0,0,1], [0,0,0]],
[[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [1,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,0,0]],
[[1,1,0], [1,1,1], [0,1,1], [0,1,0], [1,1,0]],
[[1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,0], [1,0,0]],
[[0,0,1], [0,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,0,1], [0,0,1]],
[[0,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,1,0], [1,0,0], [0,0,0]]
], 
        partTypes=[5,5,5,5,5,5],
        shapeType=31)
w.field("NAME")
w.record("PolyZTest")
w.save("MyPolyS")
```

Here is what the above output looks like in  Esri ArcScence:

[image]